# How do I pass an integer from my main app into a separate js File?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, undefined, react-bootstrap

So I'm making a larger code using React Bootstrap and I'm working on a Dropdown list which works from the backend database.

```
                  <Dropdown>
                    <Dropdown.Toggle
                      variant="success"
                      id="dropdown-basic"
                    ></Dropdown.Toggle>
                    <Dropdown.Menu>
                      <DDL options={parts} cid={7}></DDL>
                    </Dropdown.Menu>
                  </Dropdown>
```

DDL.js is the way I solved mapping the Array read from my database and then listing it in the dropdown.

```
const DDL = ({ options }, cid) => {
  console.log(cid);
  const filtered = options.filter((option) => option.catID === cid);
  console.log(filtered);
  return filtered.map((option) => (
    <Dropdown.Item key={option.id} value={option.nev}>
      {option.nev}
    </Dropdown.Item>
  ));
};

export default DDL;
```

The array part of the code works perfectly. But i fail miserably on loading the Category ID which is needed for my filter. I've tried several ways but it keeps getting undefined value. The one you see is just the most recent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are destructing props in the wrong way.cid should be inside curly braces

```
 const DDL = ({ options ,cid}) => {
 console.log(cid);
 const filtered = options.filter((option) => option.catID === cid);
 console.log(filtered);
 return filtered.map((option) => (
<Dropdown.Item key={option.id} value={option.nev}>
  {option.nev}
</Dropdown.Item>
   ));
  };

 export default DDL;
```

Comment: I tried that but when I did I might have messed up something in the main code. Thank you for the help! It works now!

Answer (score 1):

well you need to put the `cid` inside the curly braces as below:

```
const DDL =  ({ options, cid})
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-worker-c0cj7?file=/src/Test.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
const DDL = ({ options, cid}) => {
  console.log(cid);
  const filtered = options.filter((option) => option.catID === cid);
  console.log(filtered);
  return filtered.map((option) => (
    <Dropdown.Item key={option.id} value={option.nev}>
      {option.nev}
    </Dropdown.Item>
  ));
};
```